# Is Azure Cloud Service Local Storage encrypted?

Tags: azure, security, encryption

Is Azure Cloud Service Local Storage encrypted?

I would like to utilize Local Storage for my worker role as a scratch disk for image manipulation.  I'm currently using an encrypted Azure file share, but the performance isn't great.  I'm concerned that if I start using Local Storage my data may not be encrypted at rest.  I haven't been able to find definitive information about encryption and Local Storage.

Microsoft clearly allows blob and file services to encrypt data using Storage Service Encryption (SSE) and its trivial to enable this via the Azure Portal.

When configuring local storage in the cloud service definition I don't see any options related to encryption.  There's also no mention of Local Storage in the [Azure data at rest white paper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-encryption-atrest).

It looks like [Azure Disk Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption) supports encrypting both OS and data drives, but again, I didn't see any mention of Local Storage or PaaS in the Azure Disk Encryption page.